# I Installed Python 2.7.7 on my Linux Server but it's still using 2.6.9?

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

How do I change the default python version so I can use it with Django,  MongoDb and pyMongo?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using actually Amazon Linux  AMI.

Comment: Maybe give this a try https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Comment: The problem is I just realized I installed django under 2.6.9. Might have to to do a clean installation again.

Comment: it doesn't really matter if it's 2.6.9 or 2.7.7 right?